# Wordpress: Schema not displaying in different language page

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm adding [structure data](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data) to a wordpress site via the `index.php` file. Basically when I navigate to `localhost` I'm able to see the schema being render in the head. Which is where im rendering the `$context['schema']`.

[image]

However, when I navigate to `localhost:3001/es` the spanish version of the site what I get is an empty array. I don't understand why since is the same `index.php` file that is used for the sites in my understanding.
[image]

Now the implementation of the schema is as follows:

```
#index.php
/**
 * Setup schema for homepage touts
 */

$context['schema'] = array_map(function($tout) {
  if ($tout->item_scope) {
    return array(
      '@context' => 'https://schema.org',
      '@type' => $tout->item_scope,
      'name' => $tout->tout_title,
      'newsUpdatesAndGuidelines' => $tout->link_url,
      'datePosted' => $tout->post_modified,
      'expires' => $tout->custom['tout_status_clear_date'],
      'text' => $tout->link_text,
      'category' => 'https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q81068910',
      'spatialCoverage' => [
        'type' => 'City',
        'name' => 'New York'
      ]
    );
  }
}, $context['homepage_touts']);

$programSchema = array_values(array_filter(array_map(function($program) {
  if ($program->getItemScope() === 'SpecialAnnouncement') {
    return array(
      '@context' => 'https://schema.org',
      '@type' => 'SpecialAnnouncement',
      'name' => $program->program_name,
      'category' => 'https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q81068910',
      'datePosted' => $program->post_modified,
      'expires' => ($program->custom['program_status_clear_date'] ?
                      $program->custom['program_status_clear_date'] : ''),
      'governmentBenefitsInfo' => array(
        '@type' => 'GovernmentService',
        'name' => $program->program_name,
        'url' => $program->structured_data_url,
        'provider' => array(
          '@type' => 'GovernmentOrganization',
          'name' => $program->government_agency
        ),
        'audience' => array(
          '@type' => 'Audience',
          'name' => $program->audience
        ),
        'serviceType' => $program->category['name']
      ),
      'serviceOperator' => array(
        '@type' => 'GovernmentOrganization',
        'name' => $program->government_agency
      ),
      'spatialCoverage' => array(
        'type' => 'City',
        'name' => 'New York'
      )
    );
  }
}, $context['featured_programs'])));

$context['schema'] = array_merge($programSchema, $context['schema']);

$context['schema'] = array_values(array_filter($context['schema']));

if ($context['alert_sitewide_schema']) {
  array_push($context['schema'], $context['alert_sitewide_schema']);
}

$context['schema'] = json_encode($context['schema']);
```

Why would the spanish page not be loading the schema but the main page is? Isn't the same file being used for all languages?